# Error when testing an ng Project with Phantom J S

Tags: angular, jenkins, webpack, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use PhantomJS for my Angular testing so that I can integrate it with Jenkins. 
I already modified the karma.conf.js and polyfills.ts as described in other forums or guides. When I run ng test I get the following error though.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: Object is not a function (evaluating 'Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵdefineInjectable"])({ factory: function ThemeService_Factory() { return new ThemeService(); }, token: ThemeService, providedIn: "root" })')
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:181922

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: Object is not a function (evaluating 'Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵdefineInjectable"])({ factory: function ThemeService_Factory() { return new ThemeService(); }, token: ThemeService, providedIn: "root" })')
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:181922

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I didn't find any solution for my problem. Using additional imports in the polyfills did not solve it. 
Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance